# Android: How to make the content below the custom layout focusable?

Tags: android, layout, android-linearlayout, android-windowmanager

**I have the following layout:**

```
<!-- TODO: MAKE EVERYTHING BELOW THIS LAYOUT FOCUSABLE-->
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/original"
                android:layout_weight=".1"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="New Text"
                android:layout_weight=".6"
                android:id="@+id/textViewSourceText"/>

            <Button
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".2"
                android:text="X"
                android:id="@+id/closeButton"/>

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/translation"
                android:layout_weight=".1"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".9"
                android:text="New Text"
                android:id="@+id/textViewTranslatedText"/>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Which produces:**

[image]

Mentioned Layout is displayed at the top of all views using:

```
windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
            mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            mParentLayout = (LinearLayout) mInflater.inflate(R.layout.result_layout,
                    null);
            textViewSourceText = (TextView) mParentLayout.findViewById(R.id.textViewSourceText);
            textViewTranslatedText = (TextView) mParentLayout.findViewById(R.id.textViewTranslatedText);
            WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LOCAL_FOCUS_MODE,
                    PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

            params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.CENTER;
            //params.x = 0;
            //params.y = 100;

            windowManager.addView(mParentLayout, params);
```

Problem is that i cannot focus on the any other content if layout is displayed.

I would like to ask:

How can I do the content below focusable please?

Many thanks for any advice.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are two options you can try :

1- use the `WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE` when defining the `params`.

2- make the textviews focusable :

```
textViewSourceText.setFocusable(false) ;
textViewSourceText.setFocusableInTouchMode(false) ;

textViewTranslatedText.setFocusable(false) ;
textViewTranslatedText.setFocusableInTouchMode(false) ;
```

Comment: Thanks, but i thought that content under the layout is focusable, this means that for example page in the browser which is under the displayed custom layout should to be scrollable.